# i want to edit the required field of html5 how can i do that?

Tags: html

I have used the **HTML5** required field but I want to edit the attributes of that field.

For Example:

I have input field of username. If we left empty the input field the box of red color appears with a text written inside `required` I want to change the color of that box or I want to change the inner text of that box. What can be possible solutions. I Google this but couldn't find the appropriate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own CSS to style the form fields considered valid or invalid. Remember, you can use: `:required` in CSS styling elements using the required attribute and we can stylize valid or invalid fields using: `:valid` or: `:invalid`.

**Required:**

```
input:required {
   color: #00FF00;
}
```

**Valid/Invalid:**

```
input:invalid {
   background-color: #FF0000;
}

input:valid {
   background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Comment: Note that the `title` attribute of the `input` may affect (at least in Chrome) the inner text of the built-in validation box.

Answer (score 5):

you can use css pseudo classes to style invalid / valid fields:

```
input:invalid {}
input:valid {}
```

Comment: If you wanted to change the styles of the validation popup, i'm pretty sure it's currently impossible.. to alter the validation text you could use the setCustomValidity() method.

Comment: yup i was trying to change the styles of popup message but any way your answer helped.Thanksss